# Smartphone air cooler vs smartphone water cooler

Tags: smartphones, cooling

I have a Samsung s21 Ultra that i want to use as a laptop. I'll be running Linux on it together with some other resource intensive applications. Because of this i expect the phone to get quite hot so i want to buy a cooler that i can attach to the phone.

There are two types of smartphone coolers available. The first one uses air to cool the phone and the second uses water. Here is an [example of the first](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001349183825.html?spm=a2g0o.search0304.0.0.26f82315ssBmOm&algo_pvid=b1afd14f-6e6a-43d5-ba5e-0eb6edfda36b&algo_exp_id=b1afd14f-6e6a-43d5-ba5e-0eb6edfda36b-37) type and heres an [example of the second](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001021674329.html?spm=a2g0o.search0304.0.0.26f82315ssBmOm&algo_pvid=b1afd14f-6e6a-43d5-ba5e-0eb6edfda36b&algo_exp_id=b1afd14f-6e6a-43d5-ba5e-0eb6edfda36b-10) type.

I am inclined to go for the water cooled one because that one seems to be the most quiet one. However i am a bit concerned that the performance of this cooler will degrade after a while when the water inside slowly heats up.

An air cooler doesn't have that problem but is a lot more noisy. My question is: Does anyone have any experience with either of the two and if so could you tell me something about how well and how long they perform?

Thanks

Comment: If you want good phone cooling, try getting an ROG phone or something

Comment: @irsu85 whats a ROG phone?

Comment: A smartphone made for gamers, pretty over the top, but it does have high perforamnce because of built in active cooling